# Convert .eps to .xfig

Tags: graphics, conversion

This is a quick one.

I've seen many post asking how to handle a .fig file. I need the opposite, I have a .eps file and need to convert it to .fig format.

Is a there a simple procedure for this just using Windows?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possibly related: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/4xsj786Jyfw

Comment: Thanks, I have already saw that one. Isn't there any more recent source?

Comment: You can't (in general) convert it what you can do is include it into a fig object so that you can use xfig to add lines and text to the image. Use the picture tool to drag a rectangle to hold the eps then just browse to add the eps

Answer (score 2):

You can't (in general) convert it. What you can do is include it into a fig object so that you can use xfig to add lines and text to the image. Use the picture tool to drag a rectangle to hold the EPS then just browse to add the EPS.